# lxd container folder sharing with host

Tags: container

I want to share a folder within a container with the host.

So far, the examples my research points to are of host folders mounted inside the container as a volume. I want the inverse.

I have a folder inside the container which I want mounted on the host. Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a working solution for this.

[This repo](https://github.com/antitoine/lxd-functions) provides a script that does UID GID mapping between the host and the container. It creates a mount on the host with the container name as a mount point name.

Not sure if there are more elegant solutions, but this works for me now.